# Error occur while sending Date of Birth in android

Tags: android

I am sending date of birth to server in format 7/18/1992(mmddyyy) but when I saw log it will send in format 7\/18\/1992.How do I rectify this error.

code:-

```
m_DateBtn = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.date_Btn);
    m_DateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
        }
    });
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
}
m_Dob = m_InputDOB.getText().toString().trim();
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        m_InputDOB.setText((selectedMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedDay + "/" + selectedYear);
    }
};
```

Comment: So the format in the log and the format you're sending it in are the same or is that a mistake? Not sure I'm understanding the error.

Comment: not same I am sending 7/09/2016 ...log show7\ /09\ / 2106

Comment: That's weird. Your question is being displayed here as "I am sending date of birth to server in format 7/18/1992(mmddyyy) but when I saw log it will send in format 7/18/1992" but when i see your question in edit mode, I can see the extra slashes. Must be some sort of escaping.

Comment: give me solution of that

Comment: first tell me which format your server take it for birth of date like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: mmddyyy................

Answer (score 0):

The quickest, easiest, and most correct fix, is to have your server unescape the string. In PHP you would use the stripcslashes function.
As an aside, the cleanest and most compatible format to pass dates to server is in the yyyy-mm-dd format, as there is no problems with localization.